# How to make a list with lists of n items

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have list

```
['Boogeyman', '66', 'Battleground', '50', 'Rodgeners', '17']
```

I want get list with list of n (for example 2) elements, i.e.

```
[['Boogeyman', '66'],['Battleground', '50'],['Rodgeners', '17']]
```

How do it use for ???

Comment: have a look at `grouper` in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). and please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: l = list(range(10))

In [2]: [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
Out[2]: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

There would be a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Inspired by the itertools answer is possible to do

```
list(zip(*([iter(range(10))] * 2)))
```

or

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list(zip_longest(*([iter(range(9))] * 2), fillvalue='x'))
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, there is `grouper` in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n

    # this will return tuples
    # return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

    # this will return lists
    return (list(item) for item in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue))

lst = ['Boogeyman', '66', 'Battleground', '50', 'Rodgeners', '17']
res = list(grouper(lst, 2))
# [['Boogeyman', '66'], ['Battleground', '50'], ['Rodgeners', '17']]
```